# How to modify the VNC server name

Tags: vnc

I've updated the hostname on my RPi3, but VNC Server is hanging onto the old name. The old name also displays in the client's list for cloud connections. I can connect to it and control it remotely, but this connection is under the old name.

I tried restarting, but that didn't do it. I reviewed the Desktop server parameter, but the value there is a set of placeholders (`$HOSTNAME$DPY`).

How can I get the server to recognize the hostname change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atleast in VNC viewer cloud connections you can right click on top of the servers icon and rename server. I do not know if name in server list has nothink to do with server name!?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I signed in at the website and I was able to change the name.

Answer (score 1):

To edit the names of the computers in your team, go to realvnc.com, sign in with your RealVNC account, and go to the "Computers" page. Click on the pencil icon next to the computer name to edit the name. The server and any viewers should update to show the new name after a short while.